# How can I get a line down the full page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make three line down the full page to differentiate this kind of timeline thing.  I would also like to put labels at the top.  This is what I have So far:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style   = {thick, dashed, gray,->,>=stealth },
  connect/.style = {thick, dashed, gray},
  coursetitle/.style  = {minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm},
  label/.style   = {text width=2cm}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,]
%a
\node[label](1) at (0,0){\textbf{A}};

\node[coursetitle](p1.1) at (5,0.5){a327};
\node[coursetitle](p1.2) at (5,-0.5){a338};
\node[coursetitle](p2.1) at (8,0){a325};
\node[coursetitle](p3.2) at (16,0){a331};

\draw[connect] (1.1,0)--(3.05,0)(3.05,0)--(3.6,0.5)(3.05,0)--(3.6,-0.5)(5.8,0.5)--(6.2,0.5)(5.8,-0.5)--(6.2,-0.5)(6.2,-0.5)--(6.75,0)(6.2,0.5)--(6.75,0);
\draw[arrow] (3.7,0.5)--(4.15,0.5);
\draw[arrow] (3.7,-0.5)--(4.15,-0.5);
\draw[arrow] (6.75,0)--(7.2,0);
\draw[arrow] (8.85,0)--(15.2,0);

%b
\node[label](2) at (0,-7){\textbf{B}};

\node[coursetitle](m1.1) at (5,-7){b212};
\node[coursetitle](m2.1) at (8,-7.5){b161};
\node[coursetitle](m2.2) at (8,-6.5){b251};
\node[coursetitle](m3.1) at (13,-7){b311};
\node[coursetitle](m3.2) at (13,-7.75){b317};
\node[coursetitle](m3.3) at (13,-6.25){b353};
\node[coursetitle](m4.1) at (16,-7){b309};
\node[coursetitle](m4.2) at (16,-7.75){b318};
\node[coursetitle](m4.3) at (16,-6.25){b324};

\draw[connect] (5.8,-7)--(6.1,-7)(6.5,-7.5)--(6.1,-7)(6.5,-6.5)--(6.1,-7);
\draw[arrow] (1.5,-7)--(4,-7);
\draw[arrow] (6.5,-6.5)--(7.05,-6.5);
\draw[arrow] (6.5,-7.5)--(7.05,-7.5);
\draw[connect](8.9,-6.5)--(9.3,-6.5)(8.9,-7.5)--(9.3,-7.5)(9.3,-7.5)--(9.85,-7)(9.3,-6.5)--(9.85,-7);
\draw[arrow] (11.7,-6.25)--(12.15,-6.25);
\draw[arrow] (11.7,-7)--(12.15,-7);
\draw[arrow] (11.7,-7.75)--(12.15,-7.75);
\draw[arrow] (14.7,-6.25)--(15.15,-6.25);
\draw[arrow] (14.7,-7)--(15.15,-7);
\draw[arrow] (14.7,-7.75)--(15.15,-7.75);
\draw[connect] (13.85,-6.25)--(14.3,-6.25)(13.85,-7.75)--(14.3,-7.75)(13.85,-7)--(14.3,-7);
\draw[connect] (14.3,-6.25)--(14.5,-7)(14.3,-7.75)--(14.5,-7)(14.3,-7)--(14.5,-7)(14.7,-7.75)--(14.5,-7)(14.7,-7)--(14.5,-7)(14.7,-6.25)--(14.5,-7);
\draw[connect] (9.85,-7)--(11.15,-7)(11.15,-7)--(11.7,-6.25)(11.15,-7)--(11.7,-7)(11.15,-7)--(11.7,-7.75);

%c
\node[label](3) at (0,-14){\textbf{C}};

\node[coursetitle](c1.1) at (5,-14){c206};
\node[coursetitle](c2.1) at (8,-14){c203};
\node[coursetitle](c3.1.1) at (13,-14){c303};

\draw[arrow] (1,-14)--(4,-14);
\draw[arrow] (6,-14)--(7,-14);
\draw[arrow] (9,-14)--(12,-14);

%line
\coordinate (A) at (current page.north);
\coordinate (B) at (current page.south);
\draw[red, dashed,thick]%, cap=round]
(A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, I can almost certainly say I am doing this a tedious and awkward way.  I am VERY new to TikZ.  Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! One of the main advantages of Ti*k*Z is that you almost never have to work with absolute coordinates. Rather, you can use the `positioning` library to place one node `right of` another node, say. Then you should not use `.` in node names, e.g. `c1.1` should become `c1-1` since the dot is reserved for anchors, i.e. `c1.1` has already a meaning given a node `c1`. I am wondering if you could add a sketch of what you wan to achieve, looking at your code it seems to me that `matrix` and/or `chains` may simplify things here quite a bit.